# Prove existence of functions $h_1$ and $h_2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $  where $\mathbb{N}$ are naturals numbers.

$1.$ If   $\lim_{n \to +\infty} h(n)= +\infty$. Prove that  there is an $h_1:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that

$(i)$ $\lim_{n\to+\infty}{h_1(n)}=+\infty$

$(ii)$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{h_1(n)}{h(n)}=0$

$2.$ If $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{h(n)}<+\infty$.  Prove that  there is an $h_2:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that

$(i)$ $\lim_{n \to +\infty} h_2(n)=+\infty$

$(ii)$ $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{h_2(n)}{h(n)}<+\infty$.

I want to solve $1$ and $2$, but I do not know how to find $h_1$ and $h_2$

I need a suggestion,
any suggestions for $1$ and $2$ thank you very much

Comment: Is $\omega$ anything in particular? And in part (*i*), why can't you take $h_1=h$?

Comment: What is $\omega$? An arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R$ or what? How can you then in 2 sum over $n \lt \omega$? I think you've done a typo in 2 - shouldn't it be "there is an $h_2: \omega \rightarrow \omega$"?

Comment: For 1), think about the square root function :)